# Copy folder into subdirectory in CMake on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmake

I have a CMake project using Makefiles on Windows, with a folder structure that looks like this (the build takes place in `build`):

```
project
|- build
   |- ...
|- otherfolder
   |- stuff
   |- more stuff
```

As a build step (pre- or post doesn't matter), I want to make a copy of `project` into `build` (excluding the `build` folder), like so:

```
project
|- build
   |- ...
   |- project
      |- otherfolder
         |- stuff
         |- more stuff
|- otherfolder
   |- stuff
   |- more stuff
```

Other options might be acceptable as well, e.g. copying to a temporary directory outside the project root before moving it into place, but CMake seemingly has no builtin support for generating temporary directories.

Things I've tried: `xcopy` has support for excluding certain files and directories, but refuses to copy even if I explicitly exclude the `build` folder. `cmake -E copy_directory` does not (from what I'm able to find) support excluding certain directories.

CMake's `file(COPY ... PATTERN build EXCLUDE ...` copies successfully, but it runs at CMake configure time and I haven't been able to find a way to make it run at build time.

I might resort to using Python and `shutil`, but it would be nice if it could be done without additional dependencies, so I'd prefer a batch file solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways for doing selectable directory copiing.

1. You can use `cmake -P` for execute cmake script at any time. E.g:

copy_to_build.cmake:

```
file(COPY . DESTINATION build PATTERN build EXCLUDE)
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_command(... COMMAND cmake -P copy_to_build.cmake)
```

2. You can prepare list of subdirectories (and files) at configuration stage, and then copy every element of that list using xcopy. This approach uses fact, that everything outside of `build` directory is not changed. Here iteration is done on configuration stage (by CMake). I am not sure, whether "for" loop works under `COMMAND` of `add_custom_command`. If it works, you can use it for iterate over entries in the shell.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
# List of elements in source directory.
file(GLOB entries RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*)
# List of commands for pass to `add_custom_command` as is.
# `COMMAND` keyword is included into list.
set(copy_commands)
foreach(entry ${entries})
    list(APPEND copy_commands COMMAND xcopy /s /i
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${entry} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/${entry}
endforeach()

add_custom_command(... ${copy_commands})
```

Comment: Thanks! The first alternative sounds like the obvious solution I missed.